# Why must the norm of a prime element in a UFD be either a prime number or a prime number squared?

Tags: abstract-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

In my professor's algebra lecture notes she says that in a unique factorization domain (UFD) of the form $\mathbb Z[\sqrt D]$ (where $D$ is some integer) the prime elements are those that have norm $p$ or $p^2$ for some prime $p \in \mathbb Z$.

Say, $P$ is a prime element in such a UFD. Then if $P \mid A B$ it implies $P \mid A$ or $P \mid B$. This means $\mathcal N(P) \mid \mathcal N(A) \mathcal N(B) \implies \mathcal N(P) \mid \mathcal N(A)$ or $\mathcal N(P)|\mathcal N(B)$.

I understand that if $\mathcal N(P)$ is a prime number then $\mathcal N(P) \mid \mathcal N(A) \mathcal N(B) \implies \mathcal N(P) \mid \mathcal N(A)$ or $\mathcal N(P)|\mathcal N(B)$ must hold true. But why must it also hold true if $\mathcal N(P) = p^2$ for some prime in $\mathbb Z$. Secondly, why only $p$ and $p^2$? Why can't $\mathcal N(P)$ be something else?

Comment: Have you explicitly calculated $\mathcal{N}(2)$, $\mathcal{N}(3)$, $\mathcal{N}(5)$, ... in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{D}]$ for a few (squarefree) $D$?

Comment: @EricTowers Do we know $2, 3, 5$, etc. are prime elements in $\mathbb Z[\sqrt D]$?

Comment: Let's compute their norms and find out (equiv. "see what happens").  Some insight comes from *actually computing examples*.

Comment: @EricTowers Erm, okay: $\mathcal N(2) = 2^2, \mathcal N(3) = 3^2$ and $\mathcal N(5) = 5^2$. While $\mathcal N(a + b\sqrt D) = a^2 - b^2D$. I'm not sure what we can deduce from that.

Comment: What happens when $D = 2$, $D = 3$, $D = 5$, ...  You skipped half of the choices in the computation.

Comment: And then, ... what about $\mathcal{\sqrt{2}}$ in $\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ and similar?  Sure, some things will have new factors involving $\sqrt{D}$, but many things will only have the factorization they had in $\Bbb{Z}$, so all primes having squared norms is "interesting" and only some of those norms being divisible by other norms is interesting.  Which norms divide what?

Comment: @EricTowers I'm having a hard time parsing your sentences.